# 3-axes quaternion rotation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, geometry, quaternions

I'm trying to create an OpenGL program where the model of a bird is supposed to follow a defined path along the surface of a sphere described by Seiffert's spherical spiral.
However, I've been stuck on getting the rotations right for quite some time now.

As a first step, I make the bird just follow a circular path in the x-z-plane:

```
// 1. Circle in x-z plane
float phi =  TWO_PI * t; // t = [0..1]

float x = boundingSphereRadius * cos(phi);
float y = 0.0f;
float z = boundingSphereRadius * sin(phi);

float rotationAngle = glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),    
                                         glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x, 0, z)),
                                         glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) - HALF_PI;
glm::fquat rotation = glm::angleAxis(rotationAngle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

The fixed `-HALF_PI` is necessary so that the bird is correctly aligned. This works perfectly fine, and similarly I could achieve a circular rotation in the x-y- and the y-z-plane.

The problem occurs when I try to accumulate all the different rotations. The path I'm trying to follow looks like this:

[image]
[image]

As a requirement, the bird's belly is supposed to always face the surface of the sphere and the bird should fly in the forward direction.

My current approach looks like this, which consists of just combining the three orientation quaternions:

```
glm::fquat rotationX  = glm::angleAxis(glm::orientedAngle(glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x, 0, z)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) - HALF_PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::fquat rotationY1 = glm::angleAxis(-HALF_PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::fquat rotationY2 = glm::angleAxis(glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x, y, 0)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
glm::fquat rotationY  = rotationY2 * rotationY1;
glm::fquat rotationZ  = glm::angleAxis(glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0, y, z)), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) + HALF_PI, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glm::fquat rotation   = rotationZ * rotationY * rotationX;
```

However, the orientation changes are completely wrong and at some angles there are jumps occurring.

EDIT:

I'm trying different circles on the sphere now where more than one rotation is necessary. For `beta = gamma = 0.0f` and `alpha = HALF_PI` the circle is again in the x-z-plane and the value of `rotationAngleXZ` is changing, while `rotationAngleXY` is either `-HALF_PI` of `HALF_PI` and `rotationAngleYZ` is either `0.0f` or `PI`. I guess I'm running into a Gimbal Lock here and I've read a multitude of articles about it, however I'm still not sure how I can prevent it in this case.

```
// 10. `Arbitrary` circles on sphere surface
// http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643130/circle-on-sphere
//
// Parameters:
//      alpha = 0...HALF_PI - For alpha = 0, the circle is just a point - For alpha = HALF_PI, the circle is a Great Circle
//      (beta, gamma) = center of circle in spherical coordinates
float phi =  TWO_PI * t;

float x = boundingSphereRadius * ( (sin(alpha) * cos(beta) * cos(gamma)) * cos(phi) + (sin(alpha) * sin(gamma)) * sin(phi) - (cos(alpha) * sin(beta) * cos(gamma)));
float y = boundingSphereRadius * ( (sin(alpha) * sin(beta)) * cos(phi) + cos(alpha) * cos(beta));
float z = boundingSphereRadius * (-(sin(alpha) * cos(beta) * sin(gamma)) * cos(phi) + (sin(alpha) * cos(gamma)) * sin(phi) + (cos(alpha) * sin(beta) * sin(gamma)));

float rotationAngleXZ = glm::orientedAngle(glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x, 0, z)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
std::cout << "Rotation Angle XZ = " << rotationAngleXZ << std::endl;
glm::fquat rotationXZ = glm::angleAxis(rotationAngleXZ - HALF_PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

float rotationAngleXY = glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(x, y, 0)), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
std::cout << "Rotation Angle XY = " << rotationAngleXY << std::endl;
glm::fquat rotationXY_Y = glm::angleAxis(-HALF_PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::fquat rotationXY_Z = glm::angleAxis(rotationAngleXY, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
glm::fquat rotationXY = rotationXY_Z * rotationXY_Y;

float rotationAngleYZ = glm::orientedAngle(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0, y, z)), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
std::cout << "Rotation Angle YZ = " << rotationAngleYZ << std::endl;
glm::fquat rotationYZ = glm::angleAxis(rotationAngleYZ + HALF_PI, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

glm::fquat rotation = glm::normalize(rotationXZ) * glm::normalize(rotationXY) * glm::normalize(rotationYZ);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is using Euler angles (axis-aligned rotations). The wiggles and jumps are because Euler angles are a bad parameterization of the space of 3D rotations. Instead, here are two alternate approaches.

**Constructing a Rotation Matrix via a Frame**

Assuming the bird is pointing down the x-axis and up in it's own local coordinate system.

Let `p = [x y z]` be the position of the bird. Let v be its velocity vector. Let

```
f = v/|v|
up = p/|p|
s = cross(f, up)
```

Now construct the matrix with rows f, up, s. Specifically:

```
[  f[0]   f[1]  f[2] ]
[ up[0]  up[1] up[2] ]
[  s[0]   s[1]  s[2] ]
```

Then generate a quaternion via GLM's `quat_cast` function.

Avoid gluLookAt because it uses the deprecated fixed function matrix stack.

**Building up via Rotations (Quaternions)**

Let `R0` be the rotation from `i` to `f`. (The angle is `acos(dot(i,f))` and axis is `cross(i,f)`)

Let `R1` be the rotation from `R0*j` to `up`. (Using matrix multiplication notation since it is easier in this context)

Let `R2` be the rotation from `R1*R0*k` to `s`.

The final rotation should be `R2*R1*R0`. Check that this rotation is equal to the matrix above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Taylor! I guess I'm looking for a different kind of solutions, where I can combine the individual quaternions for the three axes - I have an orientation quaternion for the x-, y- and z- axis as outlined in the code I've posted. From my understanding, it is possible to multiply the three quaternions in order to get a combined orientation which is the final orientation of my bird in each frame.

Comment: I've tried so many different ways to combine the quaternions without success, and I would like to give the bounty to the person that can explain how to achieve this (or maybe why it is not possible in the way I'm trying to do it.)

Comment: Sure thing! I can understand why you'd want to have a quaternion to represent the orientation in the end, but why build up the orientation via individual quaternions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have ready code for you, but how about this idea?  Assuming you already have a formula for the x,y,z location of the bird as a function of t (Seiffert's spherical spiral).  Then:

```
eye    = fn(t)
center = fn(t + dt) // where will the bird be in the next time-step
up     = normalize(eye - sphereCenter)
```

Now, gluLookAt(eye, center, up) will provide a matrix and you should be able to use that to orientate your bird.

This reference might also help:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/how-does-glulookat-work.

Hope this helps,

--Roger